# JSF Bean won't set

Tags: jsf-2, javabeans

This is very confusing.  I'm working on a simple app for a class and followed the examples but the damn Bean property just won't set.  Code follows:

Bean code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.*;
import javax.faces.event.*;

@ManagedBean(name="dist") // or @Named("dist")
@SessionScoped
public class DistanceConvertBean implements Serializable{

private static final double MILESTOKM = 1.609344;
private static final double KMTOMILES = 0.62137;

private double input;
private String convertTo;
private String outputString;

Eclipse generated getters and setters
```

Index.xhtml code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:body>
<h:panelGrid columns="3">

<h:outputText value="Distance:"/>
<h:inputText id="inDist" value="#{dist.input}" required="true">
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2"/>
    <f:validateDoubleRange maximum="10000"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="inDist"/>

<h:outputText value="Convert To:"/>
<h:form>
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{dist.convertTo}" required="true">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="km" itemLabel="Kilometer"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="miles" itemLabel="Miles"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
</h:form>
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="Convert" action="blah"/>
</h:form>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Blah.xhtml code:

```
<h:body>
<h:outputText value="#{dist.input}"/>
</h:body>
```

So I put in 10 in the InputText field in Index.xhtml and press the command button to go to blah.xhtml.  The value in blah is still 0.0.

I'm using Tomcat 7 and Eclipse Heilos and created a dynamic web project.  I do have all the JSF jars in WEB-INF/libs.  I don't understand why the bean properties are not being set.  This look exactly like those newbie codes you find in COREJSF examples.  Web.xml is using 2.5 for servlet so I shouldn't need a face-config.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<h:inputText>` is not inside a `<h:form>` element.

Put the `<h:inputText>` inside **the same** `<h:form>` as the command button:

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputText id="inDist" value="#{dist.input}" required="true">
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2"/>
    <f:validateDoubleRange maximum="10000"/>
  </h:inputText>
  <h:message for="inDist"/>
  <h:commandButton value="Convert" action="blah"/>
</h:form>
```

The same applies to your `<h:selectOneRadio>`. Put it inside the `<h:form>` where the `commandButton` is.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Handy. I thought <h:form> wasn't really necessary but only to solve unusual behaviors.

Comment: @MooCow: I warmly recommend you to put JSF aside for a while and learn basic HTML thoroughly. Then you'll get a better understanding of the UI part of JSF :)